# iframe does not store session/cookie when refresh parent

Tags: php, cookies, session, iframe

I have been searching around but there was no specific answer or any indication about the problem I am facing.

I have a domain, parent.com, which is just a full screen container of a WordPress-powered iframe.com.

I logged in into that WordPress iframe.com (which, again, was embed inside parent.com, the address bar displays parent.com).

The login was successful, and I was able to navigate around that WordPress site as a logged-in user - until I refresh parent.com.

I noticed that although I was treated as a logged-out user immediately after refreshing parent.com, navigating to the login page will actually log me in automatically - as if the session was still kept there.

**My question**: How do I refresh parent.com without what seemingly appears to be the loss of session from iframe.com?